# how to use integer value from for loop to get a list element in django template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a list of numbers in `views.py` list=[0,1,2,3,4,5] (it is not the same all the time I'm fetching it from API)
then in my `search.html` I have written the following code:-

```
{% for i in list %}
    <a href="https://example.com//{{ id[i] }}">
      <img class="row_poster" src="https://this.isapi.org/{{poster[i]}}" alt="" />
      <h4>{{title[i]}}</h3>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

where the id, poster, title are lists passed through `views.py`

**I want to get elements of each list 1 by 1** I tried adding for loop for each but the result was bad all posters render first and then titles were rendering I want to know how can I use **it to call items from the list** or any other by which I can access elements for all lists in a single loop.

I have also tried `{% with abcd=i %}` but the result was the same keep getting this error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[i]' from 'id[i]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, first create your own filter:

```
@register.filter
def get_index(lst, i):
    return lst[i]
```

Which you can then use in your template like:

```
{% for i in list %}
    <a href="https://example.com//{{ id|get_index:i }}">
      <img class="row_poster" src="https://this.isapi.org/{{poster|get_index:i}}" alt="" />
      <h4>{{title|get_index:i}}</h3>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

For information on how to register custom tags look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).